# The ionic step is not convergent when doing DFPT in VASP

Tags: vasp, dfpt

I am trying to do DFPT, during the process of moving in different directions, even I set `EIDFF=1E-8`, the corresponding ionic step is not converged, the relative error is very large, so why doesn't VASP continue the iteration process until it converges?

Here is the output:

````
       N       E                     dE             d eps       ncg     rms          rms(c)
DAV:   1     0.943832900927E+04    0.94383E+04   -0.31019E+05  1568   0.155E+03
DAV:   2     0.120322296929E+04   -0.82351E+04   -0.77605E+04  1600   0.482E+02
DAV:   3    -0.566044087668E+03   -0.17693E+04   -0.17269E+04  1984   0.216E+02
DAV:   4    -0.730799870749E+03   -0.16476E+03   -0.16421E+03  2448   0.706E+01
DAV:   5    -0.746630469831E+03   -0.15831E+02   -0.15819E+02  2672   0.179E+01    0.116E+02
DAV:   6    -0.555587568867E+03    0.19104E+03   -0.36240E+02  2432   0.560E+01    0.544E+01
DAV:   7    -0.531278321675E+03    0.24309E+02   -0.26762E+02  2384   0.354E+01    0.311E+01
DAV:   8    -0.531683478231E+03   -0.40516E+00   -0.74971E+01  2304   0.206E+01    0.253E+01
DAV:   9    -0.529663432837E+03    0.20200E+01   -0.79646E+00  2256   0.806E+00    0.118E+01
DAV:  10    -0.529236425075E+03    0.42701E+00   -0.46911E+00  2400   0.699E+00    0.472E+00
DAV:  11    -0.529378614859E+03   -0.14219E+00   -0.91241E-01  2288   0.386E+00    0.268E+00
DAV:  12    -0.529464524587E+03   -0.85910E-01   -0.16204E-01  2432   0.129E+00    0.174E+00
DAV:  13    -0.529468617306E+03   -0.40927E-02   -0.10825E-01  2144   0.130E+00    0.614E-01
DAV:  14    -0.529480576235E+03   -0.11959E-01   -0.14206E-02  2368   0.319E-01    0.341E-01
DAV:  15    -0.529481318684E+03   -0.74245E-03   -0.43508E-03  2384   0.195E-01    0.237E-01
DAV:  16    -0.529482513141E+03   -0.11945E-02   -0.28780E-03  2352   0.118E-01    0.161E-01
DAV:  17    -0.529482663314E+03   -0.15017E-03   -0.78386E-04  2640   0.100E-01    0.940E-02
DAV:  18    -0.529482716807E+03   -0.53493E-04   -0.64189E-04  2368   0.579E-02    0.676E-02
DAV:  19    -0.529482786496E+03   -0.69688E-04   -0.15945E-04  2496   0.355E-02    0.508E-02
DAV:  20    -0.529482815409E+03   -0.28914E-04   -0.59057E-05  2528   0.303E-02    0.242E-02
DAV:  21    -0.529482810547E+03    0.48627E-05   -0.27668E-05  2240   0.154E-02    0.155E-02
DAV:  22    -0.529482810966E+03   -0.41971E-06   -0.70934E-06  2480   0.805E-03    0.110E-02
DAV:  23    -0.529482810372E+03    0.59453E-06   -0.37045E-06  2368   0.663E-03    0.373E-03
DAV:  24    -0.529482809499E+03    0.87283E-06   -0.74638E-07  2256   0.249E-03    0.220E-03
DAV:  25    -0.529482809648E+03   -0.14864E-06   -0.15244E-07  2320   0.115E-03    0.139E-03
DAV:  26    -0.529482809339E+03    0.30858E-06   -0.37618E-08  1952   0.738E-04    0.741E-04
DAV:  27    -0.529482809357E+03   -0.18343E-07   -0.56623E-09  1584   0.579E-04    0.354E-04
DAV:  28    -0.529482809319E+03    0.38337E-07    0.71730E-09   976   0.252E-04    0.172E-04
DAV:  29    -0.529482809318E+03    0.14479E-08    0.14346E-08   864   0.172E-04
   1 F= -.52948281E+03 E0= -.52948281E+03  d E =-.306981E-07  mag=     1.0000
 Linear response reoptimize wavefunctions
DAV:   1    -0.529482809344E+03   -0.26288E-07    0.15377E-08   864   0.136E-04
DAV:   2    -0.529482809343E+03    0.12224E-08    0.16366E-08   864   0.694E-05
DAV:   3    -0.529482809342E+03    0.29104E-09    0.16838E-08   864   0.460E-05
 Linear response DOF=         159
 Linear response progress:
  Degree of freedom:   1/159
       N       E                     dE             d eps       ncg     rms          rms(c)
RMM:   1    -0.366569662500E+00   -0.36657E+00    0.14851E-01  3571   0.732E-01
RMM:   2    -0.347281208720E+00    0.19288E-01   -0.33190E-02  3401   0.234E-01    0.233E-01
RMM:   3    -0.342371021787E+00    0.49102E-02   -0.45993E-03  3743   0.803E-02    0.183E-01
RMM:   4    -0.342236118255E+00    0.13490E-03   -0.51509E-03  3981   0.449E-02    0.121E-01
RMM:   5    -0.342405405393E+00   -0.16929E-03   -0.39179E-03  3769   0.377E-02    0.388E-02
RMM:   6    -0.342664154463E+00   -0.25875E-03   -0.30982E-03  4296   0.204E-02    0.259E-02
RMM:   7    -0.342527856828E+00    0.13630E-03   -0.38206E-03  4349   0.123E-02    0.183E-02
RMM:   8    -0.342519133662E+00    0.87232E-05   -0.46169E-03  4228   0.928E-03    0.577E-03
RMM:   9    -0.342319480517E+00    0.19965E-03   -0.35038E-03  4393   0.671E-03    0.419E-03
RMM:  10    -0.342399184298E+00   -0.79704E-04   -0.41299E-03  4472   0.513E-03    0.347E-03
RMM:  11    -0.342345713946E+00    0.53470E-04   -0.37327E-03  4378   0.434E-03    0.254E-03
RMM:  12    -0.342325211772E+00    0.20502E-04   -0.34263E-03  4399   0.391E-03    0.174E-03
RMM:  13    -0.342353781636E+00   -0.28570E-04   -0.37494E-03  4427   0.360E-03    0.168E-03
RMM:  14    -0.342351252543E+00    0.25291E-05   -0.38598E-03  4359   0.345E-03    0.985E-04
RMM:  15    -0.342306093782E+00    0.45159E-04   -0.33549E-03  4313   0.337E-03    0.403E-04
RMM:  16    -0.342430722702E+00   -0.12463E-03   -0.44952E-03  4420   0.328E-03    0.391E-04
 Linear response progress:
  Degree of freedom:   2/159
       N       E                     dE             d eps       ncg     rms          rms(c)


```
````

Comment: Would you be able to include this output as a code block, rather than a screenshot?

Comment: @Tyberius, I just update the question.

Comment: but at each step, it doesn’t converge.

Comment: you are calculating phonon or vibration modes. This is linear response progress, not ionic optimization.

Comment: @BinhThien. but the energy difference between linear response progress and the ground state is very large, is it normal?

Comment: VASP displaces the selected atom in the selected directions adds the calculated linear response to the orbitals, and finally determines the differences in the forces. The aim is to estimate the force, and stress tensor, not the ground state. The convergence conditions in DFPT are ignored.

Comment: Was Binh's comment helpful? Have you figured this out now?